# Cancel Job Early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a script that users have been running in the command line. If they realize something before the command finishes, they will simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and interrupt the process, fix whatever, then restart it.

In my Rails app however, I am using Sidekiq to launch the worker in the background. How can I have a button in my web app to allow a user to cancel a job?

Please let me know if you need more information.

**Update: Follow on question**

Would it maybe be possible to use Ruby to `grep` for the specific Process ID and kill it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this part of man https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals and this part https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API. It seems that you can do anything with your workers. Sorry I don't use Sidekiq, so can't give you a complete decision at time.